# Azure DevOps - Identify the person triggering the build

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

We have our Azure DevOps architecture where developers commit the code in DEV branch.
we have an intermediate branch where developers provide the list of the files that needs to be moved to Production branch from DEV branch.

Based on the list, our automated pipeline will trigger and fetch the files from DEV branch and push the selected files into a feature branch and a Pull Request(PR) will be created automatically from the newly created feature branch. We have Service Account to perform all these operations.

Once the approvers review and approve the above PR, files will get merged into Production branch and Production pipeline will be triggered.

Now we need to send a notification email to the user(who provided the list of files to be deployed into Production branch), but not sure how to identify the user who triggered the build.

Can we back track the activities using Azure DevOps REST API and get the user who triggered the build ?

I am unable to identify the user who has actually triggered the build

Comment: have you taken a look to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#identity_values ?

Comment: No, this wont work as the system variables will have user who is executing the pipeline(here in this case service account) - where as I am looking for exact person who committed the code in DEV branch and provided the list of the files

Comment: So the author of the last commit in branch should be the info you need ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the list of user who approved the PR, You can use below commands of Azure CLI and Rest API in your local Powershell or Cloud shell:-

[**Reference**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops):-

```bash
az extension add --name azure-devops
az login
az devops configure --defaults organization=https://dev.azure.com/contoso project=ContosoWebApp
```

I referred the code from this [**Blog**](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/az-devops-cli-fetch-all-prs-assigned-user-deepak-dhami?articleId=6589425154756042752#:%7E:text=#%20Fetch%20the%20PRs%20in%20a%20Project%20$PRs,$PSItem%20-in%20$reviewersId%20%7D%29%29%20%7B%20$pr%20%7D%20%7D) to retrieve the reviewers of my PR.

***Script from Blog:-***

> ```bash
> # Need the UserEmail $UserEmail = 'sid@test.com' # Put the email address for the User $ProjectName = 'AzureDevops' # use this otherwise
> default project is picked  
> # generate a list of User & Groups names to search for in the PR $IDs = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList $UserObject = az devops user show --user $UserEmail | ConvertFrom-Json
> $IDs.Add($UserObject.Id)  
> # Fetch all the teams and generate a list of teams a user is member of $Teams = az devops team list --project $ProjectName | ConvertFrom-Json
> foreach ($team in $Teams) {
>     $TeamMembers = (az devops team list-member --team $team.Name --project $ProjectName |
>         ConvertFrom-Json).identity
>     if ($UserEmail -in $TeamMembers.uniqueName)
>     {
>         #$TeamObject = az devops team show --
>         $null = $IDs.Add($team.Id)
>     } }
>
> # Fetch the PRs in a Project $PRs = az repos pr list --project $ProjectName | ConvertFrom-Json  
> # Iterate over each PR to find the reviewers and check if the user or groups is present $PrsAssignedToUser = foreach ($pr in $PRs) {
>     $reviewersId = @($pr.reviewers.Id)
>     if ($IDs.Where( { $PSItem -in $reviewersId })) {
>         $pr
>     } }
> ```

[image]

***Script to call Rest API:-***

[**Rest API to get the list of PR reviewers:-**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-reviewers/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)

> ```http
> GET
> https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/reviewers?api-version=7.0
> ```

```bash
$PAT = "xxxxxxxxxxmzpx5gjccwp4xxgukniyrhga"
$OrgName = "sid24desai0738"
$ProjectName = "AzureDevops"
$ApiVersion = "7.0"

$services = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$OrgName/$ProjectName/_apis/git/repositories/7419fe97-d348-4c7e-8c69-5665884b1880/pullRequests/11/reviewers?api-version=7.0" -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")))}

$services.value
```

[**Rest API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-reviewers/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) to Get PR reviewer for particular pull request

> ```http
> GET
> https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/reposit>ories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/reviewers/{re>viewerId}?api-version=7.0
> ```

**Azure CLI command:-**

```bash
az repos pr reviewer list --id 11
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment Siddhesh. I am not expecting the reviewer of PR but the user who initiated the commit. My PR is created thru service account as I am creating it automatically.